# HttpOnlyCookie not being set after I added domain to my website

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, cookie-httponly

I'm trying to upload my first website which consists of frontend(react) and backend(django).
So when I use it on development, all works just fine, it also works fine when I search for the IP of my VPS, but the problem comes when I try to login with the domain instead of the ip, for some reason the cookie isn't set after I login, but in with the IP it does, fyi both of them use the exact same backend and frontend.
Here is the web: [website with domain](http://grizzlytechstore.com) and here is the one without domain/IP [website without domain](http://45.82.72.171/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you visit the site using the domain name, the react backend is still pointing to the ip address. And because you have debug on I can see that your login url is something like `<your-ip>/api/login`, even though the login link should be `domain.com/api/login`.

Cookies only work for the domain you logged in from, so that's your ip. You need to configure react to change the url depending on the website's `hostname`.

Also you have some CORS problems because you API is on port 8080 instead of 80.